# Error parsing text-format milvus.proto.schema.CollectionSchema: 10:3: Expected identifier, got: / unmarshal schema string failed

Tags: milvus, similarity-search

I am trying to create a collection in Milvus, load it in order to search over its data but get the following error:

> [libprotobuf ERROR /go/src/github.com/milvus-io/milvus/cmake_build/thirdparty/protobuf/protobuf-src/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc:324] Error parsing text-format milvus.proto.schema.CollectionSchema: 10:3: Expected identifier, got: /
> unmarshal schema string failed
> Assert "schema->get_primary_field_id().has_value()" at /go/src/github.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/core/src/common/Schema.cpp:86
> primary key should be specified
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'milvus::SegcoreError'
> what():  Assert "schema->get_primary_field_id().has_value()" at /go/src/github.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/core/src/common/Schema.cpp:86
> primary key should be specified
> SIGABRT: abort
> PC=0x40022d4e87 m=9 sigcode=18446744073709551610

The following is the code by which I create the collection:

```
async createDefaultCollection(): Promise<any> {
    const params = {
      collection_name: "intentions",
      fields: [
        {
          name: "intention",
          data_type: 101,
          description: "",
          type_params: {
            dim: 1536,
          },
        },
        {
          name: "intention_id",
          data_type: 5,
          description: "",
          is_primary_key: true,
        },
      ],
    };

    await this.client.createCollection(params);
  }
```

And the following is the code by which I am trying to load the collection:

```
await this.client.loadCollection({
        collection_name: "intentions"
      });
```

As soon as I call the `loadCollection` I get the abovementioned error in the milvus-standalone logs.